# Finding same title and location but different biblionumber for items in SQL

Tags: sql

Sorry if the title is a little confusing, I'm not quite sure how to best describe my issue. I'm searching for items in the table that have the same title, location, and ISBN but have different biblionumbers. Below is what I have so far (as you can see I removed all items with the location online.

This is what I have so far:

```
select title, biblionumber, i.location, isbn, count(*) from biblio
LEFT JOIN items i USING (biblionumber)
LEFT JOIN biblioitems b USING (biblionumber)
where i.location != 'ONLINE'
group by title
having count(*) > 1
```

After more digging I found something that looks like it will work, but I don't know how to translate my tables into this SQL.

```
    select * from Persons c
where name in 
(
select  Name   from(
       select Name,Value 
       from persons        
        group by Name,Value) T

group by Name
  having count(1)>1
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your query is malformed.  The `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below -

```
select title, i.location, isbn, count(distinct i.biblionumber) 
from biblio
LEFT JOIN items i USING (biblionumber)
LEFT JOIN biblioitems b USING (biblionumber)
where i.location != 'ONLINE'
group by title, i.location, isbn
having count(distinct i.biblionumber) > 1
```

Comment: This is certainly getting me closer. I'm going to keep fighting and post an update when I think I have something closer. I don't know if I was clear, but basically I need a list of items with the same title and location but different biblionumbers

So if two items are called 'Storm of Swords' and have the same location of 'FICTION' but different biblionumbers they will show up on a list next to each other. If this is making things more unclear let me know! And thank you for your swift help. I appreciate it.